# What does this perfect tense intend to say?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

> Quirrell's voice trailed away. Harry was remembering his trip to Diagon Alley - how could he **have been** so stupid? He'd seen Quirrell there that very day, shaken hands with him in the Leaky Cauldron. (Harry Potter)

What does the perfect tense intend to say?

Comment: Since the sentence uses _could_, I think you can just use _be_, _have been_, or _had been_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, No no no! Please consult some grammar books!  Neither "could he be" or "could he had been" make sense; the former has a present meaning, and the latter is utterly ungrammatical.  Only "could have been" makes sense and is grammatical.

Comment: Since when is "Could I be right?" wrong?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, that is a good question, but "Could I be right?" is definitely a present tense situation.  It means "Am I right, or am I wrong?," NOW.  "Could I have been right?" means "Was I right, or was I wrong?," a past meaning.

Comment: You said that "could he be" doesn't make sense. I guess that, for you, the question form of "they could be right" doesn't make sense. In your first comment, you were not speaking of differences between using _be_, and _have been_. Then, what I wanted to point out is that "Could he were be so stupid?" is not something said, and referring to the past event with _could_ requires another type of _past_ tense.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, "They could be right" is a present assessment, and of course it makes sense and is grammatical.  You didn't actually give the question form, which would be "Could they be right?," but I agree with you that it is okay but always refers to a present assessment/evaluation.  What other constructions do you think might work with "could" in this particular context to show a past meaning?  I am certainly willing to consider them.

Comment: @ShawnMooney Quoting what you said: "Neither 'could he be' or 'could he had been make sense." "Could [personal pronoun] be" does make sense, contrary to what you said, period.

Comment: Not period.  Far from it.  As I hope I have clearly explained before, a question using the form "Could [personal pronoun] be" only makes sense in a present evaluative/assessment context. If I have misunderstood your point (misunderstandings on my part are highly likely), please let me know.

Comment: @Shawn, kiamlaluno: Whilst it's true that *how could he **had been** so stupid?* is never valid, in such contexts it's perfectly common to say *how could he **be** so stupid?*. Perhaps it's partly because "stupidity" is often seen as an "enduring state", so if he was stupid in the past, he's still stupid now. Whatever - it's nitpicking to dispute the usage on logical/semantic grounds, since native speakers come out with it all the time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you for the feedback. I have also reconsidered kiamlaluno's feedback, which makes good sense.  Just now, I have made a substantial re-edit to my original answer, based on your comments and also those of jwpat7; I would be grateful if any of you could review it and suggest any improvements.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meaning is that Harry is recalling a past action or behavior, and, while remembering it NOW, in the present of the narrative, he is judging it as stupid.  The use of the Present Perfect here is necessary with the question word *how* together with the past modal construction beginning with the modal verb *could*.  There is a definite tone of self-criticism in the question.

*Could* + a present tense verb can show possibility, and *could have* + a past participle usually shows a past possibility that did **not** occur.  However, in WH-questions with *how,* the meaning can be quite different, as it is in your example, where the question often means that the action following *could have* **did** occur, and the questioner is asking why.  Often, the question is [rhetorical](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/figures/r/rhetorical%20questions.htm) and judgmental. (I can think of only one exception where a WH-question with *how* and *could have* is **not** judgmental: *How could I have done that?,* in answer to, for example, a policeman accusing someone of a crime when that questioner has a solid alibi. In such a context, the questioner is asking (either sincerely or disingenously) for proof or a logical explanation of how they could have possibly committed the crime, but not conceding that they had done so; neither, obviously, are they judging themselves for a crime they have not admitted to having committed. There may be other such exceptions...)

In positive sentences using *could have,* there is not necessarily as strong a tone of criticism (For example, *You could have helped* sounds judgmental, but *He could have been busy* does not sound judgmental; the latter sentence is simply speculating about a past possibility), and in negative yes/no questions (*Couldn't you have helped?*) or WH-questions with *how* (either with first, second or third person pronouns), there often is a judgmental nuance (for example, *How could I have been so stupid?*, *How could you have done that?*, *How could she have been so stupid?*).  However, the exception I provided above could be rephrased as either a negative yes/no question or a WH-question with *how* that is not judgmental:  *Couldn't he have been busy?* or *How could he have committed the crime, since he has a solid alibi?*

(In the present tense in a WH-question with *how*, *could + [be],* a similar tone of judgmentalism can be shown, but with a present, ongoing meaning:  *How could I/he/she/they be so stupid?*  Often, the difference between *How could he be so stupid?* and *How could he have been so stupid?* is negligible.)

I hope this helps.  Please let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Nothing else could be better! And I want to know one from your answer. Would you let me get an example for negative yes/no questions?

Comment: @Listenever, thank you.  Actually, because the first word of your response, "nothing," is negative, it should be followed by a positive verb: "Nothing else could be better!".

Comment: @Listenever, as for your question about negative yes/no questions, here are some examples:  "Couldn't you have cleaned the kitchen?," "Couldn't he have called first?," and "Couldn't she have let me know first?"  All three show a critical, judgmental tone, a sense of an expectation being unfulfilled.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, please don't edit out my friendliness. I will re-insert it everytime, as I plan to do now.

Comment: @ShawnMooney Please avoid adding "What a good question." Just answer the question; comments about how good the question is are irrelevant.

Comment: @ShawnMooney, I’m very lucky to get YOUR answer today. For I’ve been always in a big trouble grasping the meanings of the perfect tenses. Thank you very much. And I’ve read your comment on Jane Eyre’s semi-colon and colon question of mine. Thank you for it too.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, as I have said on ELL before, and about which I have recently posted a suggestion on meta-ELL, I absolutely refuse to refrain from being friendly here.

Comment: And keeping to say "What a good question!" is a way to be friendly? There is a reason why thanks, hi, and other phrases that don't answer the question are removed from posts: Stack Exchange sites are not forums.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I could care less what StackExchange says.  Edit me all you want, I will continue to be friendly here.  You do your thing, and I shall do my thing...  And what, pray tell, is the REASON?????

Comment: Right, your friendliness is limited to your answers; on your comments, friendliness is optional, and you can say to somebody else to go read a grammar book when you pretend that "could he be" is not grammatical. If you don't know that Stack Exchange sites are not forums, it's your fault, not mine.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I certainly apologize if my feedback seemed rude.  Really. To be honest, I do apply a different standard of politeness when answering an ESL/EFL learner's question compared to responding to an answer thereto.  In the latter case, I tend to be more direct because I prioritize accurate answers above all else on forums such as these. However, I certainly did not intend to be rude, and if I was, I apologize.  I shall review our back-and-forth, and do some soul-searching, and I really hope we can augment each other's answers in the future, and collaborate, not butt heads.

Comment: You say “could have + a past participle shows a past possibility that did not occur”.  In the present example, “how could he have been so stupid” refers to something that did occur: he *had* been stupid (apparently).

Comment: @jwpat7, please consider how the WH-word "how" cements the meaning of the question.  Is there any doubt whatsover that the stupidity happened previously in this context?

Comment: Shawn,  there is no doubt  that the stupidity happened previously, if it happened.  I added “(apparently)” because I don't know if Harry actually had been stupid.  The real point of my previous comment is that  the present example refers to something that did occur, while your answer says the construction  refers to something that did *not* occur.

Comment: @jwpat7, I undertand your question/objection more fully now.  I stand by, and perhaps expand upon, my previous answer: in a WH-question using the adverb "how", the action referred to in the Present Perfect afer "could" definitely happened, and the question is asking about the reason for it.  "How + could + [subject] + have + past participle" questions always ask about the reason(s) for an action that DID happen.

Comment: Shawn, your answer says  “could have + a past participle shows a past possibility that did **NOT** occur” (emph. added) which is the opposite of what your comment says.

Comment: @jwpat7, I have reviewed the comments you made, my answers thereto, and my original post; 24 hours later, I completely agree with you that there was some unhelpful confusion in my answer to OP compared to the comments I made to you after that. I hope I can rectify the problem in the edit I am about to make to my answer to OP.  Please check it, and let me know if you agree.  Let's work together to clarify this.  The attitude I displayed last night is sequestered in the other room, and I am hereby imposing a moratorium on providing answers or commenting  after midnight Tokyo time. :)